# Irreduciblity of polynomial by t-ary expansion of prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Assume $t$ is a positive number larger than $2$, $p$ is a prime number. We can write $p$ in t-ary expansion:

$p=a_nt^n+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\dots + a_1 t_1+a_0$ ($0 \leq a_i \leq t-1, a_n \not =0$)

And we can define polynomial $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i$ from such expansion. How can we show $p(x)$ is irreducible? What will happen for $t=2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds too good to be true, but it is a known theorem that such polynomials are always irreducible, even for $t=2$! See Corollary 2 of ["On an irreducibility theorem of A. Cohn" by Brillhart, Filaseta, and Odlyzko](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v33/cjm1981v33.1055-1059.pdf).

Comment: The proof is more difficult than that, because $n=n\cdot1$ is a perfectly valid factorization of a prime.